# How to change div data-src to image_tag in django?

Tags: html, django

I need this expression but using static tag otherwise the images are not being displayed in project.

[image]

I tried something like this. but it is not working for div tag.

[image]

I can't find anything on google.. thankyou.

Here is the output without Django tags:
[image]

With `{% static %}`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to hard-code the url. use:

```
data-thumb="{{ model.fieldname.url }}"

model = your model name,
field name = name of your imagefield
```

Comment: what is Fieldname any example?

Comment: In your models.py under any class you've one or multiple fields. 
say you have the following class
`class Images(models.Model):
 my_image = models.ImageField()`
**my_image** is the field name.

Comment: No I don't want to add image field. it's just that styling ( The image with in div tag ) tell me how to show those images.